# How to relocate marker with ng-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I separated map initialize function and ng-autocomplete into two directive

one called my-map and the other one is ng-autocomplete

my goal is to relocate the marker while I click the prediction of autocomplete

but I am unable to pass the basic variable from my-map directive to

ng-autocomplete directive

So how could I relocate my marker? Please HELP ! !

```js
angular.module( "mapDirective", [])
.directive('myMap', function() {
    
  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        

      // var map, infoWindow;
      var markers = [];
      
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.5,121);

      var map,config;
      
      var options = { 
        zoom: 7,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false
      };


      //init the map
      function initMap() {
          if (map === void 0) {
              map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], options);
          }
      }    
      
      // place a marker
      function setMarker(map, position, title, content) {
          var marker;
          var markerOptions = {
              position: position,
              map: map,
              title: title,
              icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
          };

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
          markers.push(marker); // add marker to array
          
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
              // close window if not undefined
              if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                  infoWindow.close();
              }
              // create new window
              var infoWindowOptions = {
                  content: content
              };
              infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
      }
      
      // show the map and place some markers
      initMap();
      
      setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(23.5,121), 'my location', 'Just some content');
     


    } //link function
  } //return  
    
})
.directive('ngAutocomplete', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',


    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      options: '=?',
      details: '=?',


    },

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

      
     
      //options for autocomplete
      var opts
      var watchEnter = false
      //convert options provided to opts
      var initOpts = function() {

        opts = {}
        if (scope.options) {

          if (scope.options.watchEnter !== true) {
            watchEnter = false
          } else {
            watchEnter = true
          }

          if (scope.options.types) {
            opts.types = []
            opts.types.push(scope.options.types)
            scope.gPlace.setTypes(opts.types)
          } else {
            scope.gPlace.setTypes([])
          }

          if (scope.options.bounds) {
            opts.bounds = scope.options.bounds
            scope.gPlace.setBounds(opts.bounds)
          } else {
            scope.gPlace.setBounds(null)
          }

          if (scope.options.country) {
            opts.componentRestrictions = {
              country: scope.options.country
            }
            scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(opts.componentRestrictions)
          } else {
            scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(null)
          }
        }
      }

      if (scope.gPlace == undefined) {
        scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {});
      }
      google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
        var result = scope.gPlace.getPlace();

        
        if (result !== undefined) {
          if (result.address_components !== undefined) {  //點一下對的地址

            scope.$apply(function() {

              scope.details = result;

              controller.$setViewValue(element.val());



        // I couldn`t get map variable from the other directive to relocate marker
              
              console.log('result',result)

              var place = result;
              var mapCenter = place.geometry.location;
              map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
              map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
              
              marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                  url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png',
                  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
              }));





        //-------------------------------------------------// 
            });
          }
          else {
            if (watchEnter) {
              getPlace(result)
            }
          }
        }
      })

      //function to get retrieve the autocompletes first result using the AutocompleteService 
      var getPlace = function(result) {
        // console.log('result',result)
        var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        if (result.name.length > 0){
          autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(
            {
              input: result.name,
              offset: result.name.length
            },
            function listentoresult(list, status) {
              if(list == null || list.length == 0) {

                scope.$apply(function() {
                  scope.details = null;
                });

              } else {
                var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(element[0]);
                placesService.getDetails(
                  {'reference': list[0].reference},
                  function detailsresult(detailsResult, placesServiceStatus) {

         

                    if (placesServiceStatus == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                      scope.$apply(function() {

                        controller.$setViewValue(detailsResult.formatted_address);
                        element.val(detailsResult.formatted_address);

                        scope.details = detailsResult;

                        //on focusout the value reverts, need to set it again.
                        var watchFocusOut = element.on('focusout', function(event) {
                          element.val(detailsResult.formatted_address);
                          element.unbind('focusout')
                        })

                      });
                    }
                  }
                );
              }
            });
        }
      }

      controller.$render = function () {
        var location = controller.$viewValue;
        element.val(location);
      };

      //watch options provided to directive
      scope.watchOptions = function () {
        return scope.options
      };
      scope.$watch(scope.watchOptions, function () {
        initOpts()
      }, true);


    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="step_map_box"  ng-controller="mapCtrl as ctrl">

<div class="address_input_row row">
<div class="address_input_box col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">



<input type="text" class="demo_insert form-control address_input" id="demo_address_input"
           ng-class="ctrl.addressInput(ctrl.step()==1)"
           ng-required="false"   
           ng-model="ctrl.newItem.address"
           ng-autocomplete="ctrl.newItem.address"
           marker = "ctrl.map.marker"
           ch-input-width 
           >
</div>
</div>
<div id="step_map" class="step_map" ng-style="ctrl.mapInview(ctrl.step()==1)" my-map></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a plunkr for this ?
Also its probably nice to have a service to share data between angular components and maybe use events to notify the map that it needs to move the marker

Comment: For `angularjs autocomplete` you can refer a example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCqIPbu1the6Nrm3Rgic?p=preview).